# Skip empty rows while copying

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have this script in Google Sheets which is able to archive range **`Sheet1!A5:H`** to Sheet2

```
function tc() {
    var reference = 'sheet1!A2'; 
    var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(reference);
    rng.setValue(rng.getValue()+1);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
    var source = ss.getRange ("Sheet1!A5:H");
    var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    var lastRow = destSheet.getLastRow();
    destSheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
    source.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

The issue is that this will also archive all empty rows from that range.

Is there a way how to skip archiving empty rows from a given range?

I tried to add something like **`var filtered_input = source.filter(String);`** but this didn't do the trick. Can someone help me out?

Sheet1 looks like:

[image]

Sheet2 looks like this after running the script 2 times:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about this modification? I think that you can use `getValues()` and `setValues()` in your situation, because `contentsOnly: true` is used to `copyTo()`. So please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var lastRow = destSheet.getLastRow();
destSheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
source.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1), {contentsOnly: true});
```

#### To:

```
var values = source.getValues().filter(function(e) {return e.some(function(f) {return f})});
destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

#### References:

- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object))
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

If I misunderstood your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.